# Combine internationalized string with noninternationalized in fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

In my FXML file I have

```
<Label text="%label.total" />
```

And in properties file I have

```
label.total=Total
```

However, I want to have `Total:` on my screen. And not only for this label but for many labels which are in fxml file. I don't want to add `:` to properties file because it seems to be wrong because here we must keep only strings for different languages.

Is it possible to combine anyhow `"%label.total"` with `":"`? Or another solutions are used this case?

Comment: I cannot find an easy way to do this. If you could use resource resolution in expression bindings (i.e. `text="${'%label.total'+':'}"`), it would work, but the resource resolution is not parsed in that string (which is kind of understandable). Additionally, if a resource bundle were treated in an expression binding the same way as a map (and if you used a key without a `.`), you could do `text="${resources.labelTotal + ':'}"`, however that doesn't work either (it just looks for a `getLabelTotal()` method in `ResourceBundle`). The latter seems like it should be supported.

Comment: The only way I managed to do this at all was to dump all contents of the resource bundle into a `Map`, and put the `Map` in the `FXMLLoader`'s namespace prior to loading the FXML, which is spectacularly ugly. (Probably this solution is worse than using two labels, one with the text, and one with just the `:`.)

Comment: Sometimes, I wish the methods in JavaFX controls weren't `final`.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Well, there are good reasons for that, but yes, I know what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems like it should be easier than it is. The FXML loader has the resource bundle automatically in its namespace with the key `resources`. If the resource bundle were a `java.util.Map`, then

```
<Label text="${resources.labelText + ':'}$ />
```

would work (with the key in the properties file changed to `labelText`). However, the `FXMLLoader` doesn't treat a resource bundle the same way as it treats a map, so this just ends up looking for a `getLabelText()` method in the resource bundle. It may be worth a feature request to allow accessing resource bundle properties in the same way as map properties.

So one potential solution is to copy the resource values you need into a map. The following works with your original properties file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.util.HashMap?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>


<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">

    <fx:define>
        <HashMap fx:id="resourceAccess"
            labelTotal="%label.total"
        />              
    </fx:define>

    <Label text="${resourceAccess.labelTotal + ':'}" />

</VBox>
```

Note that you can add as many properties into the same map as you need, just add additional attributes. This feels a bit artificial, but it works.

You could also do this in Java code when you load the FXML:

```
    ResourceBundle resourceBundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle(...);

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(...), resourceBundle);

    Map<String, Object> resourceAccess = new HashMap<>();
    for (String key : resourceBundle.keySet()) {
        resourceAccess.put(key, resourceBundle.getObject(key));
    }
    loader.getNamespace().put("resourceAccess", resourceAccess);

    Parent root = loader.load() ;
```

Then the FXML

```xml
<Label text="${resourceAccess.labelTotal + ':'}" />
```

will work without the `<fx:define>` block. Again, though, this solution prohibits using `.` in the resource keys (or at least you would have to translate them to something else in the Java code: `resourceAccess.put(key.replaceAll("\\.","_"), resourceBundle.getObject(key));` or similar).

It is not immediately apparent that any of this is better than the (perhaps more obvious) workaround:

```xml
<HBox><Label text="%label.total"/><Label text=":"/></HBox>
```